# How to add txt file to array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, txt

I want the data from the txt file to be in an array
My txt file contains names written one after the other on a new line:

```
Sophia
Emily
Mary
Linda
Madison
Susan
Lily
...
```

I want them in the table

```
name = [ 'Sophia', 'Emily', 'Mary', 'Linda', 'Madison', 'Susan', 'Lily', ...]
```

it -> `...` means that there is still n amount of data, eg it's thousands

i open my file with

```
with open('dane.txt') as x:
    contents = x.read()
```

I'm not sure if it's correct but it's reading the data so far

i wanted to use

```
import numpy as np
name=np.loadtxt("dane.txt",dtype="str")
```

but i don't know why i get "Import "numpy" could not be resolved"

Comment: is `numpy` installed?

Answer (score 0):

first did you try to pip install numpy on your machine.

secondly you can do that natively in python with this function

```
def get_names(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        array = f.readlines()
    return array
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `numpy` for that. You can simply do:

```
with open('dane.txt') as x:
    contents = x.readlines()
```